# Is HTMLPurifier really that bullet-proof?

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

I saw Kohana framework allowing users to optionally use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) against any possible XSS attacks.

I thought HTMLPurifier was meant to allow standard-compliant output of the HTML.

Does it help avoid XSS attacks 100% or probably to great extent? Or you would suggest something else.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for every possible piece of software, it can not be **perfect**, and there is always a risk that someone somewhere one day can find a security hole and exploit it.

So, no-one will tell you "*it help avoid XSS attacks 100%*"...

But, each time I've head of HTMLPurifier, it was in great terms -- and I've used it successfully a couple of times, and will use it again for some future projects.

So, I think that "*probably to great extent*" is your answer ;-)